# (SQL Vertica) Create a new table dropping the rows with duplicates in a single column

Tags: sql, vertica

I am currently trying to write a query on SQL vertica that will delete the first row in which there is a duplicate value in a specific single column. I am using SQL Vertica. Does anyone know how to do this?
** Update**

I have found that the duplicates are infact in the primary key but they have an associated timestamp. So the idea is that if a duplicate is located in the primary key, I want to remove the rows with the old timestamp. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: DO you have any unique key other than the  specific single column

Comment: If you drop any duplicates for that specific column, then that will technically be a unique key, but I haven't set anything up

Answer (score 1):

*Assume you have a primary column in the table*

**Create a test table and insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  exam_id INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id,exam_id) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO test (id,exam_id) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO test (id,exam_id) VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO test (id,exam_id) VALUES (4,2);
```

delete query

```
delete from test where id in (

select id from (SELECT 
   id, 
  exam_id,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY exam_id
      ORDER BY exam_id
   ) row_num
FROM 
   test
ORDER BY 
   id) x where row_num =1) ;
```

output

```
  select * from test;
```

Comment: I have 264 other columns, would this method still be viable?

Comment: @PhysicsIslyfe yes you can

Comment: so running this, I have found that the duplicates are infact in the primary key but they have an associated timestamp. So the idea is that if a duplicate is located in the primary key, I want to remove the rows with the old timestamp. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: @PhysicsIslyfe   Can you add sample dataset it will easy to give a solution, as I understand you can change the order by close with your timestamp column

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **'duplicate is located in the primary key'**?

It is not possible to have more than one row in the same table with the same primary key